# how can I set .htaccess for existing files and folders

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

Can any one help me in .htaccess.

My use case is, if there is index.php in the directory http://domain_name/user/ then load index.php else set rewriteRule to call forbidden.php.

I did a bit but not succeed yet. .htaccess code on my server is-

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond ^(.*)$/index.php !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ forbidden.php?handle=$1

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is an easier way to do what you want. There is no need for rewriting, simply define which page acts as the entry page. In the .htaccess file you can define:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
ErrorDocument 404 /forbidden.html
```

Now, if anybody calls your directory http://www.example.com/user/, the page http://www.example.com/user/index.php will be shown.

If the file *index.html* does not exist, the server will return an error, so you can define an appropriate error page. With a leading /, you can define a single error page in the root directory, without the / it will look in the relative directory *http://www.example.com/user/forbidden.php*.

Comment: Thank a lot. I did it in other way, but this one is an easier way so, I will change my code.